# How to check current order of rows in sortable table?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

Working on a project "sortable" (rows vertically :)) list of items, but I met the problem and I don't know how to solve it.

each row got own id. How can I check new order then save it into database so next time I will load data it will be displayed in "saved" order ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the items a classname. When the items are sorted they will have the right order in the classnames-array.
For example:

```
<div id="list">
   <div class="item">item 1</div>
   <div class="item">item 2</div>
   <div class="item">item 3</div>
</div>

$('.item').each(function(){
    //save item[n] to your database using $.ajax
});
```

Comment: Thank you, will test, then will post the description :)

Comment: One more question if I can .... ;)
each element keep a id, how to pull those ids ?

Comment: If you move the item to a different position in the list, the id will move along with the item.

Answer (score 0):

try to save a new field somewhere (could be table "configuration") where save the model table name and the type of sorting and on the init method of the jquery table uses the field to sort quickly on frontend at load time

Comment: Thanx Federico :)